# Are these two sets same? $\{x \in \mathbb Z \mid x>5 \}$ and $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb Z \land x>5 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider two following sets:

1. $\{x \in \mathbb Z \mid  x>5 \}$
2. $\{x \mid x \in \mathbb Z \land x>5 \}$

Is there any difference between two sets above?

Comment: Exactly the same set, just described in two different ways.

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd prefer the fist form as it is justified by the Axiom Schema of Compehension. The second starts out notationally as a class and we have to spend a tiny thought that it is actually a set.

Comment: What about $\{x>5  \mid x \in \mathbb Z \}$? Would that be correct?

Comment: $\{x > 5|x \in \mathbb Z\}$ would describe the same set.  But it wouldn't be standard.  I think you are worrying too much. Math isn't about coding and decoding things in a secret language.  It's about doing math.  Any notation $\{$objects$|$ condition on objects$\}$ that accurately describe what you want will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading these through:

Set $1$ contains "any integer which is greater than $5$"

Set $2$ contains "any number which is an integer and greater than $5$"

It's clear to see they are the same thing;.

Comment: I am sorry, but wouldn't your description of the Set 1 be more suitable for the second set? "any number (x) which (|) is an integer and greater than 5 ($∈ℤ∧>5$)

Comment: And description of the second set more suitable for the Set 1

Comment: I'm stupid, and you're right. I put them in the wrong order. I'll switch them around

Comment: Who says that $x$ has to be a number a priori? I'd say that set 2 contains "any **object** which is an integer and greater than 5". Then again, I don't know if object is a well-defined term and I have hardly any training in set theory.

Comment: @MarsPlastic - We don't need to worry about the word "object" here. We can just say the second set contains *anything* that is an integer and greater than five.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Well, then we'd have to worry about what a **thing** is, right? Don't bank on the English language to save us by melting the words. ;-)

Comment: No, of course you don't need to worry about what a thing is. In a set theory "thing"="set"="whatever there is", in a perfectly ordinary sense. Doing set theory doesn't demand you pretend to lose your grasp of basic terms.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two sets contain the same elements, they are therefore equal.
According to the standard set notation, the first thing that is mentioned is the element, in this case $x$, and the second thing that is mentioned is what type of property enjoy: $ x \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $x > 5$. That is the case of the second set.
In the first set, the element and one of its properties are mentioned first, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. That does not make any difference in terms of the second set